# How to use regex in Portia visual scrapy?

Tags: python-2.7, web-crawler, scrapy, portia

I can able to annotate the web pages using Portia web crawler, my question is how can use the Regex while extracting the data.

For Example,

I have extracted Location filed from a page

Output looks like,

Location : Location xyz,abc

[image]

But I need only the xyz,abc values.

I have googled for solutions, but not getting more information.

Could you explain about regex in Portia scrapy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use capture groups to extract the data so in this case:

```
Location: (.*)
```

This tells portia to extract all data following the `Location:` string.

If for example you only wanted to extract all of the data between `Location:` and the  `,` you could use the following:

```
Location: (.*),
```

You can also place information inside the capture group so all data up to and including your pattern is extracted.